# ggplot graphs appearing empty when using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems  using ggplot with Rmarkdown.
I have a code that is supposed to return a ggplot graph.When I execute the code in a R session it works but the same code returns an empty plot when using R markdown.This is the code I am using in the R session

```
    m<-ggplot(data=t,aes_string(x=v,y =t$cnt_pct))
m+geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="#FF0000",color='black')+geom_text(aes(label = cnt_pct),vjust=-0.2)+ggtitle(paste(v,paste("graph")))+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ylab("percent")+geom_line(aes_string(x=v,y =t$keshel_pct),group=1,size=2)
```

This is the code I am using in the Rmarkdown

```
m<-ggplot(data=t,aes_string(x=v,y =t$cnt_pct))
m+geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="#FF0000",color='black')+geom_text(aes(label = cnt_pct),vjust=-0.2)+ggtitle(paste(v,paste("graph")))+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ylab("percent")+geom_line(aes_string(x=v,y =t$keshel_pct),group=1,size=2) 
plot(m)
```

The only diffrence between the two is that with the Rmarkwond a plot(m) line is added.
For some reason the plot command makes the graph empty, when I remove it and run the Rmarkdown no graphs are returned.

This is the graph empty

[image]

This is the graph working in a session of R

[image]

Anybody has any idea what is my mistake?

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1) your plot syntax has issues. `aes_string` takes strings referring to column names, but you're passing a variable `v` for x and direct column data `t$cnt_pnt` for y. Check some `ggplot` examples to get the syntax right.

2) The `plot(m)` statement shouldn't work for two reasons: first, you `print` ggplot objects, not `plot` them. Second, you are not assigning the `m + geom_bar(...)` statement to anything, so even if your `plot` statement did work, you'd get the plot without the `geom_bar(...)` stuff. Try e.g. `y = m+ geom_bar(...); print(y)` instead.